# Repeat Zone is not adding values as expected

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to plot a freefall function with drag. Because I have two variables that rely on each other I need to solve it numerically. For some reason the passed velocity in the repeat zone is not being added correctly.

On the first pass, I'm adding 0.098 to the velocity(0) so the velocity should be 0.098. Okay check.

[image]
[image]

Now we jump ahead to the third iteration. I'm still adding roughly 0.098. So the total velocity should be ~0.098*3 = **0.29** Except its 0.21?

I don't think I've done anything incorrectly. What gives? I don't know if this is a bug or not.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. You could simplify the case and post on issue tracker. You don't need 3 iterations, you can see the bug on the 2nd iteration: the "math: power" node reports a wrong value.